How to use a Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) Yum repository server on CentOS
I have created a yum repository server on RHEL. That server work on RHEL client machine. I want use this server on CentOS client machine. I have create a repo file under the /etc/yum.repos.d/x when i perform the yum update on CentOS, getting me error It was impossible to connect to CentOS Server
Here is repo file which i configure in CentOS
[yumserver-BaseOS]  
name=rhel yum server  
baseurl=https://test.com/repos/rhel-9-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms  
enabled=1  
gpgcheck=1  

[yumserver-AppStream]  
name=rhel yum server  
baseurl=https://test.com/repos/rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms  
enabled=1  
gpgcheck=1


What's the exact error you're getting? Are you using the exact same repo file on RHEL and CentOS? Does it really have name:  instead of name=?

It's name=, I update my questions.
Error List
https://test.com/repos/rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#60 - "Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user."
Trying other mirror.
It was impossible to connect to the CentOS servers.
This could mean a connectivity issue in your environment, such as the requirement to configure a proxy,
or a transparent proxy that tampers with TLS security, or an incorrect system clock.
You can try to solve this issue by using the instructions on https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors.

What CA is your server's certificate signed with? Did you put it in the trusted root CAs on the RHEL box but not on the CentOS box?

Created self signed certificate
